# Unable to fill input element without a form using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

Using CasperJS i'm trying to simulate a user action that consists in importing an xml file into a single page web app that was written with backbonejs: [try.activeeon.com](http://try.activeeon.com/studio/)

1) the user clicks on "Import" that is an "a" html tag

```
<a id="import-button" href="#" class="pointer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></i> Import</a>
```

2) the user selects a file in the dialog, that is handled by an "input" html tag without a "form"

```
<input type="file" id="import-file" style="display:none"/>
```

3) the web app loads the contents of the file

Now with CasperJS my script waits until the page is loaded using waitForResource() then simulates a user click using thenClick then using evaluate() sets the value of the "input" html tag by calling setAttribute and calls click() but nothing happens, i tried using fill() and it seems there is no way to fill an input without a "name" attribute, also the captured screenshot is always empty, it seems the web app didn't react ... i also tried to dispatch a "change" event on the input element after click() without any effect.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.start('http://try.activeeon.com/studio/', function() {
    this.echo("Page title: " + this.getTitle());
    this.viewport(1366, 768);
});

casper.waitForResource("gears.png", function() {
    this.echo('gears.png has been loaded.');        
});

casper.thenClick('a[id="import-button"]', function() {    

    this.wait(2000, function(){

       this.evaluate(function(){
            var inputElement = document.querySelector('input#import-file');        
            try {
                inputElement.setAttribute('value', 'file.xml');            
                inputElement.click();
            } catch(err) {
                console.log("---> oups " + err);
            }        
        });

        this.echo('-----------------------------------------');

        //this.page.uploadFile('input#import-file','file.xml'); 
        this.fill('input#import-file', {}, true);

        this.echo('-----------------------------------------');

        this.wait(2000, function() {

            this.capture('test-image.jpg', {
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: 1366,
                height: 768
            });
        });
    });        
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Did you try with casper.fill function? http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill

Comment: Yes i tried, it had no effect and from the doc: fill() function takes fields referenced by the 'name' attribute and the input tag i want to fill has no 'name' attribute.

Comment: I see. I think your question is more to how can i fill a file input witch casper.

Comment: You can't fill an file input with JS but phantomjs has a function uploadFile. What happened when you try it?

Comment: I tried to add casper.then(function(){this.page.uploadFile('input#import-file','file.xml');}); after the waitForResource call and nothing happened in the logs even if the filename is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative to fill() method called evaluate()

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate

Comment: And how would you use it? `fill` is a convenience function which uses `evaluate` internally.

Comment: I guess you can use `evaluate` method without the need of a form element being present, where as, `fill` method requires the form element to be present

Comment: Yes, that is true. But how do you solve the file upload with `evaluate`?

Comment: You are right, it will not help in file upload. I actually landed here via google search, as I myself was looking for a way to populate input element without form element being around, and later found via casperjs docs that `evaluate` does that, but didn't realize that, the actually issue in the question above was about file upload. May be the title of the question can be updated to specifically represent that the issue is regarding file upload. Thanks.